# How to implement a scalable, unordered collection in DynamoDB?

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key-design, secondary-indexes

I am looking into implementing a scalable unordered collection of objects on top of Amazon DynamoDB. So far the following options have been considered:

1. Use DynamoDB document data types (map, list) and use document path to access stand-alone items. This has one obvious drawback for collection being limited to 400KB of data, meaning perhaps 1..10K objects depending on their size. Less obvious drawback is that cost of insertion of a new object into such collection is going to be huge: Amazon specifies that the write capacity will be deducted based on the total item size, not just newly added object -- therefore ~400 capacity units for inserting 1KB object when approaching the size limit. So considering this ruled out?
2. Using composite primary hash + range key, where primary hash remains the same for all objects in the collection, and range key is just something random or an atomic counter. Obvious drawback is that having identical hash key results in bad key distribution -- cardinality is low when there are collections with large number of objects. This means bad partitioning, and having a scale issue with all reads/writes on the same collection being stuck to one shard, becoming subject to 3000 reads / 1000 writes per second limitation of DynamoDB partition.
3. Using global secondary index with secondary hash + range key, where hash key remains the same for all objects belonging to the same collection, and range key is just something random or an atomic counter. Similar to above, partitioning becomes poor for the GSI, and it will become a bottleneck with too many identical hashes draining all the provisioned capacity to the index rapidly. I didn't find how the GSI is implemented exactly, thus not sure how badly it suffers from low cardinality.

Question is, whether I could live with (2) or (3) and suffer from non-ideal key distribution, or is there another way of implementing collection that was overlooked, or perhaps I should at all consider looking into another nosql database engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "shooting from the hip" answer, what you end up doing may depend on how much and what type of reading and writing you do.

Two things the dynamo docs encourage you to avoid are hot keys and, in general, scans. You noted that in cases (2) and (3), you end up with a hot key. If you expect this to scale (large collections), the hot key will probably hurt more and more, especially if this is a write-intensive application.

The docs on Query and Scan operations (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) say that, for a query, "you must specify the hash key attribute name and value as an equality condition." So if you want to avoid scans, this might still force your hand and put you back into that hot key situation.

Maybe one route would be to embrace doing a scan operation, but just have one table devoted to your collection. Then you could just have a fully random (well distributed) hash key and do a scan every time. This assumes you always want everything from the collection (you didn't say). This will still hurt if you scale up to a large collection, but if you always want the full set back, you'll have to deal with that pain regardless. If you just want a subset, you can add a limit parameter. This would help performance, but you will always get back the same subset (or you can use the last evaluated key and keep going). The docs also mention parallel scans.

If you are using AWS, elasticache/redis might be another route to try? The first pass might code up a lot faster/cleaner than situation (1) that you mentioned.